# custom data labels in xlsxwriter

Tags: python-2.7, xlsxwriter

I am create a fairly complicated graph using xlsxwriter and I need the data labels to be different than the values of the data looking through the documentation, I see that I can add data labels the following way

```
chart2.add_series({
    'name':       '=Sheet1!$J$1',
    'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$22',
    'values':     '=Sheet1!$J$2:$J$22',
    'data_labels': {values: True}
})
```

The problem is that the data labels for my graph need to be different than the values, I need to point to a different part of the sheet to get my labels something like:

```
'data_labels': 'values_from_cells'=Sheet1!$K$2:$K$22
```

within Excel this is very easy to do, 
 1. right click on the graph,

2. right click format data labels
3. label contains: values from cells
4. I then select the cells I want and it creates the data labels

is this a functionality of xlsxwriter?

Comment: Unfortunately that feature isn't supported.

Comment: will it be at some point @jmcnamara ?

Comment: Probably. But probably not in the short term.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! xlsxWriter is a great library and I understand that not every feature can be unsupported, and Excel is tough to code around I certainly don't know enough to implement it myself so thank you!

Comment: @jmcnamara any updates?

Comment: @VMAtm It will probably be added in the next month or two. There is a GitHub [Feature Request](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/343) for it. If you add a +1 comment or watch the thread you will get an update when the feature is implemented.

Comment: @jmcnamara Thanks for information, visited the thread, added comment in it. Have a nice day!

Comment: You made a typo in the code you show, you need to write: 'data_labels': {'value': True}. However this does not solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Custom Data Labels**

*The custom data label property is used to set the properties of individual data labels in a series.*

I think that is what you searched for and i found the documentation here:
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_charts.html

Just search for "Custom Data Labels" and the first big Heading should be it.